# Is it OK to contact the hiring manager of a company that asks for an interview?

Tags: professionalism, interviewing

I was recently asked for an interview (this past Friday) after submitting my resume to a job portal for some company. I got back to the HR with my availability, but she hadn't emailed me back even after today, and I have a pending internship offer, so I called the office directly and asked if the position is still open. I said that I emailed back on Friday (it was actually 10 minutes after HR initially emailed me), but I hadn't heard anything back, so I was just making sure the position was still open.

Is this frowned upon?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I disagree with this. I read a ton of articles that advise contacting the hiring manager directly instead of dealing with HR. But that's just in getting the process started.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I'm not saying it's a perfect science. Agreed to disagree though :)

Answer (score 6):

It's a bit late to ask after you've already committed the action.

However, in general, there's nothing wrong with what you have done, although you might have waited another day. I'm assuming that "today" is Monday - that's only one working day since your reply, and if they're trying to balance a calendar of interviews, they might not confirm your response until they can do everyone.

Generally, a company that has invited you to interview wouldn't suddenly close the position without informing you.

Answer (score 2):

As a hiring manager, I will say that being directly contacted by a potential candidate can be annoying, but you can also win points by doing it.

Here's why: it shows you are MOTIVATED to learn about the job, and are being proactive about looking out for yourself.  In my book, if a candidate can figure out how to contact me, has done some research about our company and can genuinely articulate why they want to work for us and why they are the right man/woman for the job - that puts them well ahead of the pack.

If someone reading this chooses to do this, be humble, apologize for the direct contact, and be ready to take full advantage of their attention if you are lucky enough to get it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to chillout. I have had it take months from the application until the interview. And months from the interview to the job offer. One day service from HR is unrealistic to expect especially at the entry level which is most likely the least important task she is doing right now. The time of year you are asking it also affects how soon they will respond.

Let me explain what could be higher than you in her rankings of work to do (some of these assume a small company 1 person HR):

- Filling vacant senior positions
- Doing end of the year close out work especially if benefits providers
  are changing
- Making sure all current employees are set up for next year's benefits
- Using up all of her vacation time before the end of the year
- Covering for other employees using their vacation time before the end
  of the year.
- Payroll
- Handling performance issues including the paperwork to fire people
- Handling year end performance appraisal problems including setting up the information for an automated system.
- Sitting in on other interviews
- Working with a vendor to set up a rollout of a new HR system at the
  start of the year
- Working on the paperwork for a mass layoff (they are common at this
  time of year)

No one likes someone who bugs them about a job interview or offer. You can ask once or twice (generally with more than a week between) but no more than that without getting labeled a pest that no one will want to work with.  It is not their problem that you have another potential job offer and want fast action. It is not their problem that you need a job as soon as possible. They have other priorities and you need to understand that. Being a pest can rapidly move you from good candiate to don't hire. Making someone look unresponsive and have to take time explaining to the hiring offical why she didn't have an interview set up in minutes is a bad move.

Comment: "It is not their problem that you need a job as soon as possible." They might lose a good candidate who would be a good fit and worth a lot of money (including all the money they wasted on the hiring process), to a worse company *simply because the employee doesn't have time to wait*. There's a lot of reasons why someone will de-prioritise you. Your *entire job* during the hiring process is to make sure that they're keeping you in the loop, that you're aware of your options, and that they're not wasting your time.
Your list is just reasons you make sure you're polite and respectful about it.

Comment: @dewords, that is an unrealistic idea. People doing the hiring also have full-time other jobs and frankly if they lose someone because of a delay that's OK. There are other people to take the job.